# How to configure workflow in alfresco workdesk?

Tags: alfresco

I have installed alfresco community 4.2 on my laptop. Also i have downloaded alfresco workdesk & configured it to use my local alfresco repository instead of default one.

Now i am not able to figure out how to get workflow features on content i uploaded in workdesk UI as well as how to proceed with case management features as clubbing multiple files to create one case etc.?

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have done some more research & found out that one can use alfresco enterprise edition & install workdesk enterprise trial for same. This trial is a preconfigured case management example which has lots of features which can be used as yardsticks such as creating case folders with multiple files, workflow etc.

Now depending upon information/documentation you have got, one can extend it for further use.